# Rails: CSV Export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm using the built in csv function `require 'csv'`. But when I try to export the data it only exports records from the current page (with 10 entries) and not all. What should I change?

My sales.controller.rb:

```
def index
 @sales = Sale.accessible_by(current_ability).order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @sales.to_csv, filename: "sales-#{Date.today}.csv"}
  end
end
```

My sale.rb Model:

```
def self.to_csv
 attributes = %w{created_at id brand token customer_id orderid user_id product channel1 channel2}
 CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
   csv << attributes

   all.each do |sale|
     csv << sale.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: It's because you're using `paginate` to get the records in the @sales variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all records instead of `pagination` then

```
def index
   @all_sales = Sale.accessible_by(current_ability).order("created_at desc")
   @sales = @all_sales.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv { send_data @all_sales.to_csv, filename: "sales-#{Date.today}.csv"}
   end
end
```

Enjoy ...!

Comment: Thank you very much! (and sorry for the late response!)